# css for textbox in asp

Tags: css, asp.net

I want to write css for textbox in asp.I'm familiar with html,php. Struck to convert html css to asp css.

css for html input

```
input[type=text],textarea,select,input[type=password]{
float:right;
margin-right:20%; 
width:155px;
}
```

I want to convert this to input boxes

```
  <asp:textbox runat="server"></asp:textbox>
  <asp:dropdownlist runat="server"></asp:dropdownlist>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want, **SIDE NOTE**. You should give ID to each and every control. Whether it is `ASP` or `HTML INPUT`

Comment: I need to follow a style for all textbox in html,so I write css which is suitable for all.

Comment: What do you want to style the textbox or dropdown?

Comment: for both as which I used in css for html.

Comment: shall I use <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size=18 maxlength=50 required> in asp

Comment: @user3386779: Yes you can use that way

Answer (score 1):

You need to find something which has the `type` attribute equal to `text` in HTML

**CSS**

```
input:not([type]), input[type="text"] {
        background: green;
    }
```

or make the HTML explicit.

```
<input name='t1' type='text' id='txt1' />
```

*Now you can customize the CSS attribute according to your requirement.*

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CssClass` property and then style it as you require. For example

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="MyTextBox" CssClass="MyCss"></asp:TextBox>
```

and then style it using `MyCss`

Further info **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**